# Cast column as type in hibernate criteria

Tags: java, hibernate

I've been dealing with a problem in my application that has me forced to change the HibernateQuery in a way that casts the existing DateTime column I have within my database into a date for further processing.

I've looked around a little on here already and found a supposed solution using sqlGroupProjection which ended up looking like this for me.

```
Projection dp = Projections.sqlGroupProjection("CAST("+sp.getIname()+" AS DATE",
                                               "CAST("+sp.getIname()+" AS DATE",
                                                new String[] {sp.getIname()},
                                                new Type[] {StandardBasicTypes.DATE});
```

This does work to some the extent that it now generates this in the SQL statement

```
CAST(ierstelltAm AS DATE)
```

Which would be correct if it wasn't for the fact that something is now missing. Usually when Hibernate generates these statements they're given unique identifiers, one of them being y[i]_ and the other somehow relating to the table/entity used in the syntax of entity[i]_.

Since these are all inbuilt hibernate functions I had expected the above method to generate something along these lines

```
CAST(auftrag8_.IErstelltAm AS DATE) as y1_
```

based on the fact that the code previously generated using the criteria system did look like this.

```
auftrag8_.IErstelltAm as y1_
```

The question is now how do I correctly cast something to another data type using hibernate criterie, if it's not the sqlGroupProjection method mentioned in other places -- or is this a syntactical/logical error on my part?

Comment: why do you want to cast? you can use Hibernate Restrictions to query. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html

Comment: @dassum The application collects data for data analysis. In this case the cast to DATE needs to happen because the only relevant part of the timestamp is the actual day it happened. Without a cast we get a lot of split-up records because the actual DateTimes are compared instead of just the part that is relevant for us.